# Get a Task out of consecutive async methods (not in parallel)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have yet another question on how to use the await/async pattern in a certain situation.

Let's say I'm inside a method which is looping on a collection of items, and I want to execute some stuff in parallel. So, I create a `List<Task>` and for each iteration of the loop I start some work in the background and add its `Task` to that list. At the end of the method, I'll just call `Task.WhenAll` on that list.

Now, let's say that inside my loop, I have two async methods that can't be executed in parallel, that is, the second one needs to be called after the first one is completed.

**Without** optimizations, the code would look like this:

```
// Lets assume I have an items list inside each loop iteration
await FirstMethodAsync(items);
await items.SecondMethodAsync(item => item.SomeProperty);
```

Now, since the loop could go ahead while those two methods are called, this approach is really inefficient.
*Note*: I want the main method to keep running while those two chained async methods run in the background.

**Second approach**: I have my `List<Task>` ready and I add a new Task at each iteration of the loop. The problem is, the second method must be called *after* the first one. This is my solution so far:

```
// Let's assume my List<Task> is simply called tasks
TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
FirstMethodAsync(items).ContinueWith(t1 => items.SecondMethodAsync(item => item.SomeProperty).ContinueWith(t2 => tcs.SetResult(null)));
tasks.Add(tcs.Result);

// Later on, at the end of the loop and right before the method returns
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This works, and the control returns to the loop iteration as soon as I call the first thread, which is what I wanted to achieve. So, I got rid of the two `await` operators and the whole solution seems to be fine.

I'm just not sure this is the best approach: having to create a `TaskCompletionSource` and calling those two nested `ContinueWith` methods makes the code rather bad looking and sure enough there is a nicer way to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what's wrong with the `await` approach? What makes it "inefficient"?

Comment: I mean the fact that using the `await` operator blocks the method until those two awaited calls complete, instead I want to execute the rest of the main method in parallel with those two chained methods in a background thread, to optimize the performances.

Comment: So, why not just make a separate method containing those two `await` operators?

Comment: Yeah that would work and I could just add the Task of the whole method to the list, but I was looking at an elegant/clean way to do that inside the body of the main method, and without having the overhead of an additional async method to call.

Comment: Breaking into a separate method is definitely the best approach. [`ContinueWith` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html), as I describe on my blog.

Comment: If you really want it all inside the main method, you can have an async anonymous function that you immediately invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best (as in, *cleanest*, *most likely to be correct*, and *easiest to maintain*) solution is to use a separate method:

```
  for (...)
  {
    tasks.Add(BothMethodsAsync(items));
  }
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);


async Task BothMethodsAsync(... items)
{
  await FirstMethodAsync(items);
  await items.SecondMethodAsync(item => item.SomeProperty);
}
```